# Windows 10 Home Version 1607 Tor app missing

Tags: windows-10, tor

I am unable to find the Tor app in programs, also it's not showing using 'Shell:AppsFolder' command in run box. At the moment I have a Tor icon pinned to the taskbar and I run it from there, but I want to create a tile and remove it from the task bar. I suspect that once I remove it, it will disappear. How do I find the app, or is a Tor re-install the only answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Found the app lurking in my downloads folder in a Firefox folder. Problem solved, pinned it from there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A re-install may not be the only answer, but it may be the best answer.  If the menu item is missing, you cannot be sure that is the only part missing.  I would go so far as to remove and reinstall the app.

Answer (score 0):

The default installation location is usually under `c:\Program Files\Tor Browser` or `c:\Program Files (x86)\Tor Browser` depending on your os version, you can create a shortcut there. that is if you didnt change the default installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the properties for the pinned program (right-click pinned icon > right-click program name > click properties), it will tell you where the file is located in the "Target" box (in most cases).